# Sending Array to PHP Web service and Returning Array from MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, arrays

**I am developing an app in AngularJS with MySQL as a back-end database. The Web service is in PHP 5.6.30.**

I would like to know what is the best way to retrieve from the table `User` of my MySQL database a list of information of each username sent to the Web service  through the `itemsArray` Array:

- The `itemsArray` Array is sent with a list of usernames;
- The `returnedArray` Array is returned from the Web service with a list of information. For each username, the idUser, Username and Password are returned to be displayed in a HTML page.

---

Structure of the `User` table from the MySQL database:

- idUser (int)
- Username (varchar)
- Password (varchar)

Sample of the data structure `itemsArray` (Array) that is sent to the Web service:

```
var itemsArray = ["admin1", "admin2", "admin3", "admin4", "admin5"];
```

Sample of the HTML to display the data returned by the Web service:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="item in returnedArray track by $index">{{ item }}</li></ul>
```

Sample of the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', 'services', Ctrl1]);

function Ctrl1($scope, services) {
    var itemsArray = ["admin1", "admin2", "admin3", "admin4", "admin5"];
    //request to MySQL BD
    services.getInfo(itemsArray).then(function(data){
      $scope.returnedArray = data.data;
    });
  }
```

Sample of the `app.js` to send request to the Web service:

```
.factory('services', ['$http', function($http){
  var serviceBase = 'services/';
  var obj = {};
  obj.getInfo = function (arrayItems) {
    return $http.get(serviceBase + 'get_info?arrayItems=' + arrayItems);
  };
  // return obj
  return obj;
}]);
```

Sample of the Web service in PHP: **(which must be completed)**

```
// GET - Get Info
  private function get_info(){
    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
      $this->response('', 406);
    }
    $arrayItems = (array)$this->_request['arrayItems'];
    $query = "TO COMPLETE";
    $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    if($r->num_rows > 0){
      $result = array();
      while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
        $result[] = $row;
      }
      $this->response($this->json($result), 200); // send user details
    }
    $this->response('', 204);   // send user detail
  }
```

Thank you *

Comment: What's the question about?.. Have you tried anything to take values from DB? Only two ways... `fetchAll` and `fetch` (last is optimal for a big scope)

Comment: Displaying user passwords - are you kidding? Your application should not even _store_ actual user passwords in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe: I created the Users table as a test = this is fictional data. I will not actually display stored users and passwords in my app. My app does not store that kind of information.

Comment: @FieryCat: I'm asking because I don't know how to solve my problem. I recently started programming, and I don't know how to manipulate properly arrays.

Comment: @Julia, possibly, then you could explain in details what your problem is... (if you haven't taken anything from server, then enable error plotting, check logs, .. to identify the original issue)

Comment: @FieryCat: there are no errors for now since the "Sample of the Web service in PHP" must be completed. That is my problem, since I don't know how to properly manipulate arrays to request and return the data as needed.

Comment: @Julia, if you haven't yet failed with something, assume, it's not the right place to ask about. Just follow "Best practices"

Comment: P.S. `if($r->num_rows > 0){` is an overhead for the current script. `while($row = $r->fetch_assoc())` - do that check as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Meanwhile, I solve my own question.**

There is the solution if someone needs it in the future:

*(Initial Problem: converting a JavaScript String Array to a PHP String Array)*

Solution:

```
 private function get_info(){
    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
      $this->response('', 406);
    }
    $arrayItems = $this->_request['arrayItems'];

    //Explode on comma
    $vals = explode(',', $arrayItems);
    //Trim whitespace
    foreach($vals as $key => $val) {
      $vals[$key] = trim($val);
    }
    //Return empty array if no items found
    //http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#114273
    $arrayItems_php = array_diff($vals, array(""));

    $usernames = implode("','", $arrayItems_php);
    $query = "SELECT idUser, Username, Password FROM User
    WHERE Username IN ('$usernames')";
    $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);


   if($r->num_rows > 0){
      $result = array();
      while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
        $result[] = $row;
      }
      $this->response($this->json($result), 200); // send user details
    }
    $this->response('', 204);   // send user detail
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you simply need:

```
$this->response(json_encode($result), 200);
```

instead of:

```
$this->response($this->json($result), 200);
```

Comment: It can be a part of framework logic... should not be the case

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like that:

```
private function get_info()
{
    if ($this->get_request_method() != 'GET') {
        $this->response('', 406);
    }
    $arrayItems = (array) $this->_request['arrayItems'];
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` = :key';
    $r = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
    // as an example
    $this->mysqli->bind_param('key', current($arrayItems));
    $this->mysqli->execute();

    $result = array(); 
    $responseCode = 204;
    while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
        $responseCode = 200;
        $result[] = $row;
    }
    // send user details
    $this->response($this->json($result), $responseCode); 
}
```